# can I get the position of my error in Dart code when using Crashlytics in Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am trying to install crashlytics in Flutter app, and I can get the error/crash in the Firebase console. after forcing a crash in my main function like this

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash(); // forcing a crash, in line 5

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

the error in console looks like this

[image]

it seems to me that the error is still in Java. I can't identify the error if it still pointing to the java code. I need to know the error position in my dart code. like for example above, it should indicate that error is in `main.dart` file in line 5. In native Android and native iOS usually it will be like that

am I missing something? is the default like that?

Comment: But isn't this a deliberate crash? It says that it was caused by calling .crash(). There isn't anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Firebase crashlytics 'crash' causes the app to crash natively. It does not occur in the Flutter engine. Try throwing a fatal exception in Dart and see the output in the crashlytics console.